# Socket connection between two devices

Tags: sockets, networking, connection, wifi

Is it possible to create a socket connection between two devices **connected to two different Wi-Fi networks?**

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up different layers of the TCP/IP layer model. Sockets are not a feature of the physical layer "WIFI" but of the upper UDP or TCP transport layers. So it doesnt really matter if your devices are connected to a WIFI network or simply connected to an ethernet switch.

Maybe you should have a look into [subnetting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

Comment: The OSI model is for the OSI protocol suite, although it is much misused and abused and misinterpreted as a general networking layer model, which was never the intent. TCP/IP has its own, prior, layer model.